# DRED GetAutoBreadcrumbsOutput() gives hresult DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: directx-12, direct3d12

Naively copy pasting from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/dred/

```cpp
winrt::com_ptr<ID3D12DeviceRemovedExtendedDataSettings> pDredSettings;
winrt::check_hresult(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDredSettings)));
pDredSettings->SetAutoBreadcrumbsEnablement(D3D12_DRED_ENABLEMENT_FORCED_ON);
pDredSettings->SetPageFaultEnablement(D3D12_DRED_ENABLEMENT_FORCED_ON);
```

```cpp
winrt::com_ptr<ID3D12DeviceRemovedExtendedData> pDred;
winrt::check_hresult(device->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDred)));

D3D12_DRED_AUTO_BREADCRUMBS_OUTPUT DredAutoBreadcrumbsOutput;
D3D12_DRED_PAGE_FAULT_OUTPUT DredPageFaultOutput;
    
winrt::check_hresult(pDred->GetAutoBreadcrumbsOutput(&DredAutoBreadcrumbsOutput)); // error
//  0x887A0004 : 'The specified device interface or feature level is not supported on this system.'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Sigh. Once again I debugged what was causing a non-zero `hresult` when it was explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12deviceremovedextendeddata-getautobreadcrumbsoutput).

---

I didn't read the fine print

> DRED settings must be configure **prior to creating a D3D12 Device**. Use D3D12GetDebugInterface to get an interface to the ID3D12DeviceRemovedExtendedDataSettings object.

Also `GetAutoBreadcrumbsOutput()` will error with `DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE` unless `ID3D12::GetDeviceRemovedReason()` is returning `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG` so I recommend adding the following line before calling:

```cpp
_ASSERTE(device->GetDeviceRemovedReason() == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG);
```